# Compiling directive after appending html with ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that appends li items to list. Every li has an div, that include the template. I compile it after I append html, but ngInclude doesn't work. It does not include the  specified template.

```
 scope.attrs.itemTpl = 'dimension-item-tpl.html';

 elemnt.find('ul').append(generatedList);
 $compile(generatedList)(scope);
```

tried two examples, html after append:

```
 <li class="col-xlg-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" data-item="creative_filename">
    <div ng-include="dimension-item-tpl.html"></div>
 </li>
 <li class="col-xlg-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" data-item="size">
    <div ng-include="dimension-item-tpl.html"></div>
 </li>
```

and the second:

```
<li class="col-xlg-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" data-item="creative_filename">
    <div ng-include="attrs.itemTpl"></div>
</li>
<li class="col-xlg-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" data-item="size">
   <div ng-include="attrs.itemTpl"></div>
</li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/4zhLtjbw/

Comment: could you show your complete directive definition?

Answer (score 0):

**In the first example**

You are missing single quotes.

> ngInclude = angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a
>   string constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g.
>   src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

try this.

```
 <li class="col-xlg-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" data-item="creative_filename">
    <div ng-include="'dimension-item-tpl.html'"></div>
 </li>
 <li class="col-xlg-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" data-item="size">
    <div ng-include="'dimension-item-tpl.html'"></div>
 </li>
```

*Note single quotes.*

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: I would like to create a directive, that does not need ngRepeat, because there is some additional functionality on the directive, that doesn't play good with ngRrepeat.

Comment: edit your post and show a simplified version of your directive definition